# SQLite statement syntax error near where

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am having problems with the syntax of my SQL statement, the LogCat says the problem is near WHERE. Where did i go wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var inName = "Test Name";
var inNumber = "Test Number";
db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES ( ?, ?) WHERE ? NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM SoccerPlayer)',[ inName, inNumber, inName ] });
```

Any help or advice will be gladly accepted, this is the last piece of the puzzle for my project. When I am done with this i can already rest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is **?** can you give more detail

Comment: Those ? would base the values inside the bracket which are [ inName, inNumber, inName ].

Comment: can you try static value for *where **Name** not in ..*

Comment: can you see my answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` does not take a `WHERE` projection while `UPDATE` does.

Possibly you wanted either

```
INSERT INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES (?, ?)
```

or

```
UPDATE SoccerPlayer SET Club=? WHERE Name=?
```

or in case you want to update in case the `Name` already exists or insert otherwise,

```
INSERT OR UPDATE INTO SoccerPlayer(Name,Club) VALUES (?, ?)
```

where you need the table to have some relevant constraint such as `Name TEXT UNIQUE`.

---

Edit:

> I want my insert function to ignore the insert if the Name already exists

Then you can make the `Name` column `UNIQUE` as above and use `INSERT OR IGNORE` instead of `INSERT OR UPDATE`.

Comment: This is for my insert function, it worked on my update function.
I want my insert function to ignore the insert if the Name already exists.